# std::forward_list::insert_after thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++14, forward-list

In a shared `std::forward_list` is it safe for multiple threads to call `insert_after` concurrently if they are guaranteed to never call it with the same position iterator? It seems like this could be safe given that insert is guaranteed not to invalidate other iterators, and the container has no `size()` method, but maybe I'm missing something?

Edit:

I wrote a small torture test program that seems to run fine in Clang without any locking:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using List = std::forward_list< int >;
using It = List::const_iterator;

void insertAndBranch (List& list, It it, int depth)
{
    if (depth-- > 0) {
        It newIt = list.insert_after (it, depth);
        std::thread thread0 ([&]{ insertAndBranch (list, it, depth); });
        std::thread thread1 ([&]{ insertAndBranch (list, newIt, depth); });
        thread0.join();
        thread1.join();
    }
}

int main()
{
    List list;
    insertAndBranch (list, list.before_begin(), 8);

    std::vector< It > its;
    for (It it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
        its.push_back (it);
    }
    std::vector< std::thread > threads;
    for (It it : its) {
        threads.emplace_back ([&]{ list.insert_after (it, -1); });
    }
    for (std::thread& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    for (int i : list) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I know this doesn't prove anything but it makes me hopeful that this is safe. I'm not sure I can use it without some confirmation from the standard though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::list threading push\_back, front, pop\_front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843567/stdlist-threading-push-back-front-pop-front)

Comment: The duplicate is old, and things have changed.

Comment: well, OP doesn't specify C++ standard..

Comment: C++14, I just added a tag.

Comment: Any time you have multiple threads and one or more of them is a writer to a shared variable then you need synchronization.  If not you have a data race which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- I think that is an oversimplification. For example multiple threads can write to the same array as long as they are writing to different locations in that array. Similarly in my case I can guarantee that concurrent inserts will never happen at the same position.

Comment: @NathanOliver The thing is, there is no shared variable. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299099/stdforward-listinsert-after-thread-safety#comment71753230_42299210) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a shared `std::list` is it safe for multiple threads to call insert
>   concurrently if they are guaranteed to never call it with the same
>   position iterator?

No. It wouldn't be safe...(No matter what).

Inserting into a `std::list` will require access to the `previous node` and `next node` to the iterator position, and the `size` of the list.

Even if the positions are far off each other, the simple fact that [`std::list::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) is required to be *constant time* (C++11). It means each insertion will update `std::list::size()`.

---

Edit:

> In a shared `std::forward_list` is it safe for multiple threads to
>   call insert_after concurrently if they are guaranteed to never call it
>   with the same position iterator?

It's not safe. and not recommended. No STL container was designed with thread safety.

---

Anyway, lets assume some basic guarantees, lets assume a very simple version of `std::forward_list`: `insert_after` modifies the node pointed to by your iterator so that the node now points to the newly inserted node, while the newly inserted node points to the next node. So its only going to be "safe" if the iterators are at least two nodes away from each other and your allocator is thread-safe.

Illustration:

```
Initial Forward_list
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Insert K after C
A -> B -> C x D -> E
           \ /
            K
```

As you can see, `C` is read and modified. `D` may be read, while `K` is inserted.

---

As to why I said "at least two nodes away", lets take the case of one node away: Assuming two threads want to insert `K` after `C`, and `M` after `D` respectively:

```
Initial Forward_list
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Insert K after C
A -> B -> C x D x E
           \ / \ /
            K   M
```

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races):

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and
>   another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the
>   expressions are said to conflict.

Comment: Actually I'm using `std::forward_list`, not `std::list` in my code. I had written the question using `std::list` for simplicity sake but I changed it now. Interestingly `std::forward_list` has no size method so would that change your answer?

Comment: In a double linked list you are correct, but in a single linked list the only two nodes that need modifications are the node pointed to by the position argument and the newly created node, neither of which would be read or modified by another thread.

Comment: @atb, I've updated my answer to argue your comment (see the illustration). You still need to be at least two nodes away. Still, its not a guarantee. Use locks or some other library with thread safe list

Comment: In your first diagram, I don't think D would be read. The next node pointer would be taken from C and given to K. I can't imagine why an efficient implementation would need to read from D.

Comment: @atb, That is also possible, But the point is, good things can happen, bad things can equally happen. No guarantees. And whatever any implementation does, its "correct" so long as it conforms to the dictated observable behavior

Comment: I see what you're saying but there are many things that are guaranteed by the standard. In this case I don't know what is guaranteed or not but I'm hoping to find out definitively. I will have to accept a significant performance hit if I need to use locking and my test code seems to run fine without it.

Comment: @atb, I just conversed with [Howard Hinnant](http://howardhinnant.github.io/) by email about this question. Though "The standard just doesn't guarantee it, But He can't think of any way it would fail either".... With [libcxx implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/forward_list%23L1189), I think you are good to go if you can fulfill your own guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Not even **read** operations are thread-safe when another thread **writes** to a list (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725768/threading-safe-stdlist-c) for further explanations); so: multiple writes are not thread-safe:

*While reading from a list without a lock will not corrupt the list, if the list is modified while another thread is reading from it, either thread could become corrupt (i.e. crash, or produce incorrect results).*

You need some sort of locking. Period.

Comment: You may be correct but I would be interested to know why in this specific case.

Comment: It is not so simple. If, for example we have a forward list with one element then: reading its data  (`a = l.begin()->d;`) from one thread and adding an element in another one (`l.insert_after (l.begin(), X);`) should not trigger any race condition. That's because that there is no shared data accessed in both threads: the first one only read `begin` and `begin->d` and the second writes to `begin->next`.

Comment: @ShmuelH. AFAIK there is no guarantee that `begin` is thread safe unless you call the const version.  `begin()` could do something(it would be insane if it did but I think the standard allows it) and now you have a data race on the calls the `begin`.

Comment: Actually I'm using std::forward_list, not std::list in my code. I had initially written the question using std::list for simplicity sake but I changed it now. The answer  you quote is referring to std::list, would that change your answer here? If not can you explain why?

Comment: @NathanOliver [Luckily that's not the case.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements.dataraces#1)

Comment: @T.C. Oh nice.  Didn't know they added that.  Thanks.

Comment: @atb The standard says that, with a few exceptions (linked in my comment above), non-const member functions are deemed to modify every part of the object it is called on for the purposes of assessing whether there are data races. As a more concrete example, debug mode implementations may have additional bookkeeping structures that `insert_after` can write to without synchronization.

Comment: @T.C. -- I guess I was hoping that someone could tell me that this was one of those exceptions.  Neither of the alternatives (locking or writing my own data structure) are particularly appealing...but I admit I may have no choice.